# Adding together integers from given list

Tags: python, list

I have a problem: Given a list of numbers and a number `k`, return whether any two numbers from the list add up to `k`.

For example, given `[10, 15, 3, 7]` and `k` of 17, return true since 10 + 7 is 17.

How can I add together some elements in a list of integers?

Of which the code I wrote is:

```
a = [10, 15, 3, 7]
k = 17

while i < k:
    if i + i != k:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: the logic is all sort of wrong, you loop will run once and check if i+i==k, that is if 10+10=17 which is not only false but also wrong, you are supposed to use 2 different positions, then your loop will exit

Comment: You never defined a variable named `i`...

Comment: Uhm... your code is incomplete - `return` should be used inside function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each number `num` in the list, calculate `k - num` and check if that number exists in your list.

For increased performance, it's best to turn the list into a dict that counts how many times each number occurs in the input. (Lists have `O(n)` membership tests while dicts have `O(1)`.)

```
a = [10, 15, 3, 7]
k = 17

from collections import Counter

occurences = Counter(a)  # count how many times each number occurs

for num in a:
    complement = k - num

    if complement not in occurences:
        continue

    # if the number is its own complement, check if it
    # occurred at least twice in the input
    if num == complement and occurences[num] < 2:
        continue

    print('The pair {} + {} adds up to {}'.format(num, complement, k))
    break
else:
    print('No combination of two numbers adds up to {}.'.format(k))
```

Comment: I see what's happening with it now. I'm new to python so will try this and learn more on the topic. Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

this need to work, however, this is a very slow code:

```
a = [10, 15, 3, 7]
k = 17
done = False #define a flag
#use two for loops to check if two numbers add up to k
for i in a: 
    for p in a:
        if i + p == k:
            print(str(i) + '+' + str(p) + '=' + str(k))
            done = True
            break #to break out of inner loop
    if done:
        break #to break out of outer loop
if done == False:
    print('No such numbers exist.')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) with [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations

def sum_available(lst, k):
    return any(x + y == k for x, y in combinations(lst, 2))
```

**Usage**:

```
>>> a = [10, 15, 3, 7]
>>> k = 17
>>> sum_available(a, k)
True
```